# Check if a specific user reacted discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am looking for a script to check if the user that executed the command (`ctx.message.author`) has reacted to the message with a checkmark, it should look like this:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test")
    for emoji in ('✅'):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji) 
        # Here it should detect if the ctx.message.author has reacted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check via the user's ID and using `wait_for`:

```py
import asyncio # for the exception

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test")
    for emoji in ('✅'):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji) 

        try:

            # the wait_for will only register if the following conditions are met
            def check(rctn, user):
                return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) == '✅'

            # timeout kwarg is optional
            rctn, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, timeout=30)

            # then execute your code here if the author reacts, like so:
            await ctx.send("I detected the author reacting!")

        # throws this error if user doesn't react in time
        # you won't need this if you don't provide a timeout kwarg in wait_for()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, you didn't react in time!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`Member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.id)